# Creating network graph in flex

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript

Ok I had asked a question recently based on this.

But I need to narrow down more..

I need to create a network graph with nodes in flex. Once I give the input the nodes must get connected with each other if they have something in common.

The nodes must be click-able to show which other nodes it is connected to.

A simple code example will be appreciated.

Can a bubble chart be modified to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i personally think, a bubble chart is not really the right way to go ...
most simple thing - in a flex world - would be to subclass `UIComponent` twice, for, let's say, `NodeView` and `ConnectionView`, and then put all this into some container, with absolute positioning ...

other way would be to simply add a `Sprite` to a `UIComponent`, and do the same thing in plain AS3, simply subclassing `Sprite` twice ... less overhead and other problems, but will not benefit from flex features, such as styling ...

do you already have a model for the network? do nodes also have coordinates, or do you need to arrange them your self? 
or, if loaded externally, can you show some sample data?

greetz

back2dos

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
But I do not have a model. I need to arrange the nodes randomly. Probably bigger nodes with more number of connections. So how can I do the arrangement?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I think you can try [Flare](http://flare.prefuse.org/).

Take a look at the demo for Layout.